# How do I make new page when generating PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf, migradoc

I am using MigraDoc do generate a PDF document, I would like to create a new page so first data get displayed in first page, second data get displayed in second page etc... this is how I am creating my page:

```
        List<SIP_ImprovementPlans> s = db.MName.ToList();
        MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document document = new MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document();

        Section section = document.AddSection();
        section.PageSetup.TopMargin = Unit.FromCentimeter(4);
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        var heading1= paragraph = section.AddParagraph("heading1");
        document.AddSection();
        var heading2= paragraph = section.AddParagraph("heading2");
        document.AddSection();
        Heading3 etc....
```

Now to create a new page I can do this: `section.AddPage();` I have also tried `document.AddPage();`
But I get error in line AddPage(); why is that? the error says `Error   1   'MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document' does not contain a definition for 'AddPage' and no extension method 'AddPage' accepting a first argument of type 'MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document'`

If I do `document.AddSection();` it creates the new page but I want heading 1 to be in first page, heading two in second page etc... currently its placing heading1 heading2 etc... in one page and creates a new page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start a new page, simply call `section.AddPageBreak();`

`document.AddSection();` returns the new section. To add text to the new section, call AddParagraph() for this new section. Your code creates three sections, but adds all headings to the first section.